# Changing VS2010 environment variables for WIX

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I need to build two branded versions of my WIX based installer. The only difference between the the versions is a single bitmap containing the company contact details. I'd like to keep a single WIX project so I have less projects to maintain. I'm using an environment variable to alter which bitmap is inserted into the installer

```
Source="$(env.CompanyName) contact.png"
```

This works fine, however I cannot change the environment variable from within VS2010. VS2010 is compiling the WIX installers using the environment variables that were set when VS2010 started. I have to restart VS2010 to get it to pick up the new environment variable value.

I have 36 nested projects so I don't want to have to set the build variables within each project - that's why I'm trying to use an environment variable.

Does anyone know how to change one of the environment variables used by the current VS2010 instance? Or perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 8):

I do this and significantly more customization in a single WiX project.  I have a different project configuration for each variant.  So rather than "Debug" and "Release", I have for example "Debug", "East" and "West".  This only applies to the setup project.  The code projects still use "Debug" and "Release".  The WiX compiler can read the configuration value.

```
<?if   $(var.Configuration)="West"?>
  <?define CompanyName="West Coast Office"?>
<?elif $(var.Configuration)="East"?>
  <?define CompanyName="East Coast Office"?>
<?else?>
  <?define CompanyName="Debugging purposes"?>
<?endif?>

Source="$(var.CompanyName) contact.png"
```

Alternatively, you can add it to the setup project's preprocessor variables (Project Properties, Build, General), but again, you'll require multiple configurations:

```
CompanyName=West Coast Office
```

And in your Product.wxs:

```
Source="$(var.CompanyName) contact.png"
```

---

To add the configurations in Visual Studio:

1. Open the menu **Build, Configuration Manager...**

   **Create solution configurations**
2. Under **Active solution configurations** select **<New...>**
3. Type the Name (eg. **East**), Copy settings from **Release**, and **do not** create new project configurations.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the other office (eg. **West**).

   **Create setup project configurations**
5. Next to the setup project, open the **Configuration** drop down and select **<New...>**
6. Type the Name **East**, Copy settings from **Release**, and **do not** create new project configurations.
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 for **West**.

   **Delete setup project's Release configuration**
8. Next to the setup project, open the **Configuration** drop down and select **<Edit...>**
9. Select **Release** and press **Remove**, followed by **Yes** and **Close**.

   **Delete solution's Release configuration**
10. Under **Active solution configurations** select **<Edit...>**
11. Select **Release** and press **Remove**, followed by **Yes** and **Close**.

    **Assign the project configurations to the solution configurations**
12. Under **Active solution configurations** select **East**.
13. Set the setup project's Configuration to **East** and every other project's configuration to **Release**.  Tick **Build** next to each project (assuming you need all of them.)
14. Repeat steps 12 and 13 for **West**.

Now when you select each solution configuration, you should have the following settings:

```
Solution       Debug    East     West
------------------------------------------
Main Project   Debug    Release  Release
Setup Project  Debug    East     West
```

Finally, go into the setup project's properties and ensure everything is correct for the East and West configurations.  Take note of the output folder.  If that is still **bin\Release**, then the two configurations will overwrite eachother's output.  Set it to **bin\East** and **bin\West** respectively.

Comment: I see what you are getting at but I'm getting an error :

The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Alquist'  Platform='x86'

When I go into Build from the WIX project properties I can only chose between Release and Debug from the Configuration combobox.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a few steps involved, so I've added it to my answer above.